# How can I perform a quick double tap using TouchAction in Appium?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-java

I am automating my mobile keyboard, and it requires a quick double-tap on the shift key to lock the capital letters. However, when I try to double-tap the shift key, I am unable to lock the capital letters.

**This is my Java-code.**

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);

    //Perform quick Double tap on Shift key
    int shiftx = 90, shifty = 2174;

    PointOption shiftkey = PointOption.point(shiftx, shifty);
    touchAction.tap(shiftkey).perform();
    touchAction.tap(shiftkey).perform();
```

It keeps switching to the capital letter keyboard and then back to the small letter keyboard. The double-tap seems to be happening very slowly here, I think.

**Does anyone have an idea please?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to double click on an element using point options

```
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
int shiftx = 90, shifty = 2174;
PointOption shiftkey = PointOption.point(shiftx, shifty);
t.tap(TapOptions.tapOptions().withPosition(x,y).withTapsCount(2)).perform()
```